# mod_rewrite subdomain to file with 2 variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I was looking for a htaccess file who rewrite with this conditions

```
(www.)domain.de -> (www.)domain.de/index.php
(www.)domain.de?tos -> (www.)domain.de/index.php?ac=tos
```

Info: tos is a placeholder i need it dynamic

```
subdomain.domain.de -> (www.)domain.de/subdomain.php
subdomain.domain.de?tos -> (www.)domain.de/subdomain.php?ac=tos
```

Info: tos & subdomain are placeholders I need it dynamic.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What re-write rules have your tried?

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=muekschi.de
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.muekschi.de
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.muekschi\.de$
RewriteRule (.*) /%1.php` I miss the 2nd variable

Answer (score 1):

You can use these rules

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?muekschi\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?ac=%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www)[^\.]+)\.muekschi\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ /%1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www)[^.]+)\.muekschi\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1.php?ac=%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NE]
```

Comment: I take a look at the error log and found `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: Okay no more errors but didnt work. subdomain.muekschi.de dont redirect to subdomain.php. and "ac" isnt set

Comment: Do you want external redirect OR just internal rewrite?

Comment: I dont know the difference. Everything is on the same server

Comment: Are `subdomain.muekschi.de` and `muekschi.de` are pointing to same `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: try updated code now. Make sure to copy it completely in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`

Comment: the result from http://www.muekschi.de/?test are an array `Array ( [test] => )` but i need `Array ( [ac] => test)` and http://account.muekschi.de/?newUser are going to `http://account.muekschi.de/account.php?ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&ac=account.php&newUser`

Comment: Nice the main works but the subdomains are reffered to `newUser.php` i hope you can fix the last thing. You are great ty.

Comment: `The requested URL /.php was not found on this server.` maybe `QUERY_STRING` for security are server side disabled?

Comment: Now i see a next problem. If i have a url like `account.muekschi.de?news&page=3` it doesnt work. I need `account.php?ac=news&page=3`